# Show the motion of a particle occurs along a quadric surface

Tags: calculus, parametric

Given the formula $g(t)=(t \sin \theta,t\cos \theta, \sqrt{3}t),$ $0\leq t\leq4\pi$, how can I show this motion to be along a quadric surface?

Comment: The reason I didn't understand this was because my prof never covered this, some more digging gave me that $g(t)$ translated to $x^2+y^2-\frac{z^2}{3}=0$ which is an elliptic cone. For anyone asking the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your particle is travelling on an "elliptic cone". To see this, note that for any point (note that we lose $t$ dependence in our computation)
$$
(x,y,z)=(t\sin \theta,t\cos \theta,\sqrt{3}t)
$$
defined by your parametric curve, you have 
$$
3x^2+3y^2-z^2=0\implies z^2=3(x^2+y^2)
$$

Comment: @HorribleATMath no problem!